# Is there a way to send a PySide2 model through subproces.Popen?

Tags: python, popen, pyside2

In my `MainApp` I have a `QTreeView` populated by items from a `QStandardItemModel`. By clicking a button I use `subprocess.Popen` to launch a 3D software (in this case Maya2020). Once Maya is running I execute a snippet of code inside of its script editor to open a widget called `SubApp`.

I'd like to pass `MainApp`'s model data to `SubApp`'s QTreeView somehow. In my real code when I launch `SubApp` I use environment variables to send some key values (UUID and list of UUID parents) to reconstruct the model/view again. This feels over complicated and I'm wondering if there's a better way to share data?

My code: *(Note! I've included MainApp and SubApp in the same module for simplicity, but these classes are decoupled in the real thing)*

main_launch.py

```
import os
import sys
import subprocess

from Qt import QtWidgets, QtGui


class MainApp(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    """ This is the main launcher app that holds the model data
    """
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainApp, self).__init__(parent)

        # Model/View
        view = QtWidgets.QTreeView()
        model = QtGui.QStandardItemModel()
        view.setModel(model)

        # Populate data
        for i in range(3):
            parent1 = QtGui.QStandardItem('Parent {}'.format(i))
            for j in range(3):
                child1 = QtGui.QStandardItem('Child {}'.format(i * 3 + j))
                child2 = QtGui.QStandardItem('row: {}, col: {}'.format(i, j + 1))
                child3 = QtGui.QStandardItem('row: {}, col: {}'.format(i, j + 2))
                parent1.appendRow([child1, child2, child3])
            model.appendRow(parent1)
            # span container columns
            view.setFirstColumnSpanned(i, view.rootIndex(), True)

        # GUI
        btn_launch = QtWidgets.QPushButton('launch sub app')
        btn_launch.clicked.connect(self.on_launch_sub_app)

        # Layout
        main_layout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self)
        main_layout.addWidget(view)
        main_layout.addWidget(btn_launch)
        self.setLayout(main_layout)

        self.root_path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))).replace('\\', '/')

        # Copy this path when it prints and paste it into "maya_snippet"s "root_path"
        print(self.root_path)

    def on_launch_sub_app(self):
        """ Opens software (maya in this case) and then you launch SubApp from within maya's script editor.

        Is there any way to send the model data using subprocess.Popen?
        """
        # Maya location
        app_exe = r'C:/Program Files/Autodesk/Maya2020/bin/maya.exe'

        proc = subprocess.Popen(
            [app_exe]
        )


class SubApp(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    """ Running the "maya_snippet.py" code from within maya will launch this window
    """
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(SubApp, self).__init__(parent)

        # Model/View
        view = QtWidgets.QTreeView()

        # Would like to set the model from the MainApp
        model = QtGui.QStandardItemModel()
        view.setModel(model)

        # Layout
        main_layout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self)
        main_layout.addWidget(view)
        self.setLayout(main_layout)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainApp()
    window.resize(400, 400)
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

maya_snippet.py *(Run this from within Maya to launch SubApp (after you've launched Maya from MainApp))*

```
import sys

# Change root_path to the directory holding main_launch.py
root_path = 'path/to/directory/holding/main_launch'

if not root_path in sys.path:
    sys.path.append(root_path.replace('\\', '/')

import main_launch

w = main_launch.SubApp()
w.show()
```

Comment: explain yourself better besides providing a [MRE]

Comment: What version of pyside2 do you use?

Comment: I use version 5.14.2.2

Comment: Sounds like this has less to do about subprocess and more of a question of if you can restore a treeview with data? Well you already have the right idea. You need to serialize your data through a file or env variable, then have a custom method that will read and restore that data. From what I can tell there's no built-in way to do this, so you're already on the right track (and in my opinion, no, doesn't feel overly-complicated).

Comment: Thanks for the input @GreenCell. I have this setup working in my production code by sending a string of UUID's separated by spaces like this "000 123 343 223". It works, but I'd love to send the actual indices instead. When I first tried it out it didn't work, but maybe that's because it wasn't serialized? I'll do some research on that, thanks for the tip

Comment: You can also dump all of your data into lists and dictionaries using `json.dumps` which will parse everything to a string. Later retrieve all data with `json.loads`. This will be much easier than doing it yourself with a single string. What are you trying to do exactly?

Comment: It's a pipeline tool. https://mikebourbeau.com/armada-pipeline is my project. I'm currently refining the launcher app workflow. When you open a Maya file from the launcher a custom userSetup.py that Maya is told to look for via env var instantiates and docks a file manager inside of its own GUI. I'd like to just store launcher's model somewhere and then use that to set the model of the docked file manager.